# How to have a checkbox button on a table in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

When a user inputs a certain date period on a text box the MYSQL select statement picks the mobile numbers from a database for the time period and displays them. I now need to add a functionality where on each number displayed there is a checkbox that when highlighted the numbers highlighted are ignored/dropped or say do not receive an SMS.
I have tried the code below but does not work. Anyone lead me through. Is there a better way after the numbers are displayed for the user to remove the one he/she needs to send SMS to?

```
$sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT msisdn FROM customer WHERE DATE_FORMAT(time_paid, '%Y-%c-%e') BETWEEN ADDDATE('$time1',INTERVAL 0 HOUR) AND ADDDATE('$time2',INTERVAL '23:59' HOUR_MINUTE)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

echo " <table><tr><th>Mobile Number</th></tr>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["msisdn"]. "</td><td><form><input type='checkbox' name='check'>
</td></form></tr>";
}
 echo "</table>";
} else { 
  echo "No contacts to display";
}
```

Comment: Now you need to give the check box a name,  and in php check the value,  if it's checked,  delete the number or just set a column value,  and else do the inverse.

Comment: first replace `"checkbox"` to `'checkbox'`

Comment: Hello @FMashiro I don't want to delete them from the database but just exempt or remove them from the list.

Comment: In that case you should have a column called "show_number" or something, datatype TinyINT(1) and set it to 1 or 0 and then using it to filter when selecting the numbers

Comment: @Rishi why should the OP do that?

Comment: @TheCodesee : He can build the logic after fixing syntax error.

Comment: @your passing variables straight into your SQL query, you're wide open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: @Rishi Wouldn't that break the echo statement which has `"` ?

Comment: @The Codesee : brother see his edit and see my comment, I said before his edit.